# Running tests in PhpStorm for Laravel Homestead vagrant VM

Tags: laravel, phpunit, phpstorm, homestead

I've got a fresh installation of Laravel Homestead based on this: https://laravel.com/docs/master/homestead

And a fresh new project using Laravel new.

I'm trying to run the example tests through PhpStorm's "Run configurations" but I get

```
vagrant:///Users/si/vagrant/Homestead/usr/bin/php /home/vagrant/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --no-configuration /home/vagrant/Code/homestead/tests
Testing started at 00:49 ...

Process finished with exit code 1
Cannot find PHPUnit in include path (.:/usr/share/php)
```

In the PhpStorm PHPUnit settings I have the PHPUnit library loaded with "Use custom autoloader" pointing at the composer autoload.php file like this:

```
/Users/si/Code/homestead/vendor/autoload.php
```

And composer has added the PHPUnit executable at

```
/Users/si/Code/homestead/vendor/bin/phpunit
```

I'm confused as to why PhpStorm can't find this PHPUnit executable when I'm telling it to use the composer autoload to find it.

Comment: Have you configured remote php interpreter?

Comment: Yes - this all seems good, although I haven't added anything explicit for the include path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I fixed this. I had added a remote interpreter in the PHP settings, but was still using 'local' settings in the PHPUnit settings. I added a new PHPUnit settings configuration 'By Remote Interpreter' in the Languages and Framdworks > PHP > PHPUnit settings screen.

I selected 'Use custom autoloader' and specified the following:

```
/home/vagrant/Code/homestead/vendor/autoload.php
```